# how to get bayer image without converting to RGB in pylon?

Tags: c++, camera, image-formats

I want to get a Bayer format image from Basler Camera using C++. I set pixel-format to `BayerBG8` (for example) and the camera can save image data. The  image data is in `ptrGrabResult` of type `CGrabResultPtr` but how can I access to pixels value?
Using a convertor, the data convert to a pylon RGB image and is available, but how to get Bayer image without converting to RGB in pylon?

Comment: If you want people to help you, make it easy for them. Please indicate **which** camera you are using, and include a link to the corresponding documentation and show your latest/greatest code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `GetArray()` method for that, so something like `ptrGrabResult->GetArray();` should work for you.